# Exporting QGIS styles to SLD for GeoServer?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, sld

I´m starting to dive into sld creation for Geoserver 2.7.1

Therefore I´ve also looked at Qgis 2.8.2 as it can export styles to SLD.

Where I´m clueless is the big amount of used prefixes/namespaces.

```
<se:Name …
<ogc:Name …
<sld:Name …
```

QGIS SLD exports result in files with se: (symbology encoding).

Is it important for GeoServer which prefix/namespace is used in SLDs? If so, where can I find information and what should be noticed? Can you give a use case for when to choose which prefix/namespace?

Comment: Be aware that GeoServer developers do not like much the SLD that QGIS is creating. Read thread http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.geoserver.user/45488/focus=45491

Comment: Reading the SLD cookbook would be a useful start, if you haven't already seen that: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/

Comment: @user30184 it's not so much we don't like it as it is broken.

Comment: @BradHards thanks for the start, but I cannot find much regarding namespaces here? – which is the aim of my question. Do I oversee something?

Comment: I'm suggesting an alternative to using QGIS. It isn't answering the question, which is why its a comment against the question.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS does not export labels use UDIG to do styling and labeling (generate SLD) or ArcGIS ArcMap with Arc2Earth.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it shouldn't be a problem which namespace prefixes you associate with which namespace, as long as you declare the associations in the XML declaration at the top of your SLD file.